# QT4 Qtableview disable selection of rows

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using qtableview-s to show some data from sqlite tables. I have 2 tableviews  which are essentialy same. They are both showing bus stops (same model) in rows. In first table i am selecting departure and what i would like to achieve is that in second table all entries before the selected one are made non selectable so that user cannot move backward to select them. 
I was able to hide them using ***setRowHidden(row,true)*** but i would like still to see them but not be able to select them.

I tried using flags Qt::ItemFlags (using flags method in custom model) for the row but no matter what i use the rows are still selectable. Does anyone know how to disable row in QTableView so that is still shown but not selectable.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the tips/help but in the mean time i found solution (well bug in my code). It was bug in my custom model. I was returning wrong flags for item. 
For others that might try to do something similar. You have to implement **flags** method in custom model (QSQLQueryModel derived) and return flag **Qt::NoItemFlags** for items that you dont want selected. I was returning **QAbstractItemModel::flags(index)** but there are some default flags allready set.

```
Qt::ItemFlags busStopsTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
    if(index.row()>lastDisableRowID){

        return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index)|Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    }
    else
    {
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. The flags in custom model was my only idea too. I'm assuming your original data-source is QSQLQueryModel? Did you create a subclass and override, or did you create a QAbstractProxyModel?

Comment: I used subclass and override. And it is right way because i found bug in my code and it is working now. I will post solution. I never tought of using QAbstractProxyModel. Will have to check that out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could install an event filter on the QTableView and override mouse press / mouse move events (or create a class inheriting QTableView to do the same thing).

Event filter code would look like:

From the class instantiating & using the QTableView:

```
QTableView* view = new QTableView(this);
view->installEventFilter(this);
```

Create the `eventFilter` method for this same class:

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if(object == view && (event->type() == QEvent::MousePress || event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)) {
        // if statement to see if event position is on one of the rows you want to disable
            // if true, return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My application is running on device that has no mouse only keyboard. Could this also be achieved for keyboard events?

Comment: Yes it could - the event filter allows you to capture any and all events sent to the table.  in the `eventFilter` function, you would check that `event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress`.  There you would check whether the key pressed is an arrow key or whatever else allows you to select something.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make your own QTableView class and override the [setSelection](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#setSelection) and possibly [setCurrentIndex](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#setCurrentIndex) functions